# Bundling and tree-shaking node_modules into a single file

Tags: node.js, webpack

I'm trying to create an AWS Lambda Node 8 Application. I realise you shouldn't try to do npm install on Lambda, and instead upload a zip containing your scripts and the node_modules folder. However, the zip is over 7MB and contains a lot of dead-code that I'm not expecting to be run (for instance, `node_modules\node-sass\src` contains a load of c++ files which I don't think is called through node?).

I know that 7MB isn't "large" but this is just a sample application to test the waters to use Lambda and I want to nail down the concepts :). Also, to avoid confusion: the application is to compile sass on the fly, so I am trying to deploy libsass/nodesass. I know it's usually a build-time only tool!

I've tried using [backpack](https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack) to bundle my scripts, since it claims to create a single main.js file. It does create a file with a lot of external code, which *looks* like code from node_modules, but it doesn't work when run in a clean folder.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'fs-extra'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.module.exports.exports.__esModule (C:\Dev\fsdf\sass-compiler\main.js:3192:18)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Dev\fsdf\sass-compiler\main.js:21:30)
at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Dev\fsdf\sass-compiler\main.js:7837:16)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Dev\fsdf\sass-compiler\main.js:21:30)
at Object.module.exports.Object.defineProperty.value (C:\Dev\fsdf\sass-compiler\main.js:7820:18)
at __webpack_require__ (C:\Dev\fsdf\sass-compiler\main.js:21:30)
```

The only way I can make it work is to use zip up the entire node_modules folder and the main.js file. However, this produces an 8MB zip since main.js is considerably bigger than my 3KB source code!

Have I missed something, or is simply impossible to avoid zipping up node_modules? My theory is that it should be possible since Webpack doesn't need node_modules in the browser.

Comment: This is what `npm i` is for. There's no tree shaking for Node packages because they are CJS which wasn't designed to be tree-shaken. *I realise you shouldn't try to do npm install on Lambda* - why? The idea is faulty by design. There may be native modules which won't work when being copied to another system. **Notably `node-sass`**.

Comment: I believe you shouldn't npm install on Lambda since functions maybe destroyed and recreated between each run - you don't want a 50ms function to wait for a 5s npm install.

Comment: That said, I'm willing to give it a go - I don't currently know how to do that though since Lambda calls a module in my code without a chance to call npm install (although I guess I could do that from within node and spawn a new process!)

Comment: Once you have a build to deploy, I see nothing wrong in zipping node_modules. I have little experience with AWS Lambda myself but this seems reasonable. And this article suggests same thing, https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/nodejs-packages-in-lambda/ . Notice that you need to build it in Amazon Linux in order for native modules to work, also makes sense. Double check whether you need stuff you have problems with. node-sass is dev dependency, isn't it? It's unlikely you need it in production. I didn't use Backpack, but if it has problems with your setup, consider opening an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I hadn't found it. I'm currently trying to learn Docker with amazonlinux as a build machine for the sass binaries (unfortunately it is needed in production!). Zipping up the node_modules folder does seem to work, but it's larger than I'd hoped for such a simple app! The question is how to shrink it down, and whether backpack is supposed to be doing that or if I've misunderstood what the purpose of it is

Comment: I've raised an issue in backpack asking if they think node_modules is required or not after running it https://github.com/jaredpalmer/backpack/issues/130

Comment: I think you've got Backpack purpose correctly. It's only a wrapper for Webpack and Babel. I'd suggest to try Webpack directly.

Comment: @estus You don’t run npm install inside a lambda container for a number of reasons, but mainly because you’d be paying for unnecessary execution time. You can use docker with mounted host dirs for native module installation